# Div and Curl Identities

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $F$ is a vector field, I understand that the div(curl $F$) = 0. But would the curl(div $F$) have any interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $\text{div}$ takes in vector fields and produces scalar fields; $\text{curl}$ takes in vector fields and produces vector fields. Thus, given a vector field $F$, it makes sense to write
$$\text{div}(\text{curl}(F)),$$
but not to write
$$\text{curl}(\text{div}(F)).$$
So there is no interpretation because it doesn't mean anything in the first place :)

Comment: @Jon: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26854/what-is-an-intuitive-explanation-for-div-curl-f-0), and many of the others that appear on the right side of the screen.