# Is the Divergence of Curl equal to Zero for All Coordinate Systems?

Tags: vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

Is the divergence of curl equal to zero for all coordinate systems?

Even a curvilinear coordinate system such as double spheroidal coordinates?

Comment: Change of coordinates formulas are linear. This implies that if a vector is $0$ in one coordinate system, it's $0$ in all of them.

Comment: The coordinate system is irrelevant. You should read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26854/what-is-an-intuitive-explanation-for-operatornamediv-operatornamecurl-f